# How to delete Thumbs.db (it is being used by another process)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple console application that I'm trying to delete a folder:

```
Directory.Delete(folder,true);
```

I got the exception of the annoying Thumbs.db

```
The process cannot access the file 'Thumbs.db' because it is being used by another process.
```

I can't change the registry to avoid Thumbnail to process in folder

What are my options here to be able to delete the folder with everything in it?

thanks

Comment: `thumbs.db` is used/owned by the Windows shell. Make sure the folder isn't visible in any window (that there are no open views on the folder), and you should be able to delete the file.

Comment: You may want to check [this link](http://www.hardanswers.net/stop-thumbs-db-from-locking-folder-deletion-renames) which goes straight to the point without needing to hack the registry **manually**.

Comment: I normally work around this problem manually by renaming thumbs.db before I delete it. I have never tried doing that programmatically, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find out which process is blocking it with [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml). If you can't kill that process you can mark this file or folder to be deleted right after the next boot with [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);

public const int MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x4;

//Usage:
MoveFileEx(fileName, null, MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);
```

If you want to **disable the creation of "Thumbs.db"-Files** completely you can switch it off in the registry. Open the registry editor, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` and set the value of `NoThumbnailCache` to `1`. If this entry doesnt exist you simply can create it (`DWORD 32`).

For Win7 Professional / Ultimate the path to the entry is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` and it's name is `DisableThumbnailCache`.

Answer (score 0):

To delete Thumbs.db files that were residing on a network drive for Windows 10, I had to go into '**Local Group Policy Editor**' under '**User Configuration/Administrative Templates/ Windows Components/File Explorer**' and Enable the '**Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files**' setting. Then go into Task Manager and restart Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a file named **thumbs.db** is possible, by first renaming the file (e.g. into **x.db**). After renaming the file, deleting is no problem.

Comment: When the file is open in (and thus blocked by) Windows Explorer, it cannot be renamed.

Comment: ```test> Rename-Item Thumbs.db bye.db
Rename-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! This worked perfectly for a few thumbs.db files that have been "locked" for weeks.